# How to capture Caps Lock when in Remote Desktop so the connecting host doesn't process it?

Tags: winapi, remote-desktop, hotkeys, setwindowshookex, capslock

I'm using [`SetWindowsHookEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx) to make my <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key bring up an [application launcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_desktop_application_launchers) that I'm writing, blocking the actual toggling of <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>.

It works *just fine* on a local machine. However, when I try to use it on a machine that I have connected to via Remote Desktop, what happens is that the original machine processes it independently, meaning that as soon as I switch back to the connecting machine, my <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> is toggled on.

Is there another way to handle it that will prevent this issue from arising, or is this a fundamental limitation of Remote Desktop?

Comment: You should probably double-check the "Apply Windows key combinations" setting on the client, but my guess is that this can't be done.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: It doesn't affect Caps Lock unfortunately.